# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement error

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I would like to get names from one db and initiate a new table with it. I want to add more analysis, but this is my starting point where I'm already struggling and I have no idea where I made the mistake.

```
mydb = db_login()

# get team
team = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM team', con=mydb)
names = team.name.to_list()
```

this will output something like ['name1', 'name2' ...]

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS team_analyse")
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE team_analyse (name VARCHAR(50))") #todo add all needed columns
sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO team_analyse (name) VALUES (%s)" #todo initial team commit
mycursor.executemany(sqlFormula, names)
mydb.commit()
```

In the end I get the following error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: `executemany ` usually expects a list/tuple of lists: `mycursor.executemany(sqlFormula, tuple(names))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a single `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` here:

```
INSERT INTO team_analyse (name)
SELECT name
FROM team
```

Your updated Python script:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = """INSERT INTO team_analyse (name)
         SELECT name
         FROM team"""
mycursor.execute(sql)
```

The error message you are seeing is telling you that you passed a list as the parameters to bind to the statement, but not all parameters were used.  Actually, the single insert statement you were trying to run only has a single parameter.  But in any case, it is unnecessary to bring the result set from the `team` table into Python's memory.  Instead, use my suggestion and let MySQL do the heavy lifting.